# Deity Life And Death ability

Tags: dnd-3.5e, religions-and-deities

Can a deity use the *Life And Death* ability even if it is not in his **Salient Divine Abilities** list and his portfolio does not have the relevant **Suggested Portfolio** elements, like in this particular case *Death* or *Supreme*?

Assume that the **Prerequisites** for this ability are respected. (Deity has rank higher than 6 and has one of the prerequisite abilities in his list of salient divine abilities.)

Comment: It would be easier for us to edit the question and make it more understandable if you could tell us which deity you are talking about.

Also it is difficult to answer for certain, as two things you have written appear contradictory: You say "not in his Salient Divine Abilities" in the first sentence, but than say " have one of this ability in his Salient Divine Abilities list" at the end.

Comment: Right, to clarify about misunderstanding, the deity have no *Life And Death* ability, but have *Hand of Death* which is prerequisites to have ability in question.  Thor is a good example i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineRanksAndPowers.htm):

> A deity has one salient divine ability for each divine rank the deity has, plus additional salient divine abilities reflecting its status: Demigods receive one bonus ability, lesser deities receive two bonus abilities, intermediate deities receive three, and greater deities receive five.

**Only if *Life and Death* is amongst the list of salient divine abilities, the deity can use this ability.** In order for this ability to be amongst the salient abilities list, the deity must be of rank 6 or higher and *Gift of Life* or *Hand of Death* must also be amongst the salient abilities as well.

Suggested Portfolio elements are what the name implies: suggestions. Quoting:

> The information is provided as guidance and should not be taken as a rule.

Note that Death portfolio is NOT needed to use the *Life and Death* ability; but its presence would make the ability more potent (the deity would not need to rest after using the ability).

Comment: Okay, i think it's pretty much answer my question. If it's not in deity Salient Divine Abilities list then he can't use it, even if he fulfil all prerequisites. In Thor's case because all his Salient Divine Abilities already occupied.